# Listview and sharedprefs

Tags: java, android, listview, sharedpreferences

So i'm currently working on a app that i can use while training. What i'm trying to achieve here is to log what i'm doing everyday in so i can later on see how my progress is going..

This is what i have done so far.

**Mainactivity**

> 

public class Mandag extends AppCompatActivity{

```
EditText O1,R1,S1,KG1;
Button Leggtil, logg;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mandag);
    Leggtil = (Button)findViewById(R.id.leggtil);
    O1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.O1);
    R1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.R1);
    S1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.S1);
    KG1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.KG1);
    logg = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    Leggtil.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            SharedPreferences SF = getSharedPreferences("Trening", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = SF.edit();
            editor.putString("O1",O1.getText().toString());
            editor.putString("R1",R1.getText().toString());
            editor.putString("S1",S1.getText().toString());
            editor.putString("KG1",KG1.getText().toString());
            editor.commit();
            Toast.makeText(Mandag.this,"Lagt til i logg",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        }
    });

    logg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(Mandag.this, Logg.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });


}
```

**Mainactivity Layout**

> 

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Øvelse"
    android:id="@+id/ovelse"
    android:layout_weight="0.03"
    android:layout_row="0"
    android:layout_column="0" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Reps"
    android:id="@+id/Reps"
    android:layout_weight="0.03"
    android:layout_row="0"
    android:layout_column="1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Sets"
    android:id="@+id/Sets"
    android:layout_weight="0.03"
    android:layout_row="0"
    android:layout_column="2"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="KG"
    android:id="@+id/KG"
    android:layout_weight="0.03"
    android:layout_row="0"
    android:layout_column="3"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="0dp" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="148dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/O1"
    android:layout_row="1"
    android:layout_column="0" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="62dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/R1"
    android:layout_row="1"
    android:layout_column="1" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="51dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/S1"
    android:layout_row="1"
    android:layout_column="2" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="51dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/KG1"
    android:layout_row="1"
    android:layout_column="3" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="logg"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_row="27"
    android:layout_column="0" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Leggtil"
    android:id="@+id/leggtil"
    android:layout_row="27"
    android:layout_column="3" />
```

**Log activity**

> public class Logg extends AppCompatActivity {

```
String O1, R1, S1, KG1;

private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.logg);
    ListView listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
    list=new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

    SharedPreferences SF = getSharedPreferences("Trening", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy");
    String date = df.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());

    HashMap<String,String> dates=new HashMap<String, String>();
    dates.put(FIRST_COLUMN, date.toString());

    list.add(dates);

    HashMap<String,String> form=new HashMap<String, String>();
    form.put(FIRST_COLUMN, "Øvelse");
    form.put(SECOND_COLUMN, "Reps");
    form.put(THIRD_COLUMN, "Sets");
    form.put(FOURTH_COLUMN, "KG");
    list.add(form);

    HashMap<String,String> temp=new HashMap<String, String>();
    temp.put(FIRST_COLUMN, O1 = SF.getString("O1",""));
    temp.put(SECOND_COLUMN,R1 = SF.getString("R1",""));
    temp.put(THIRD_COLUMN, S1 = SF.getString("S1",""));
    temp.put(FOURTH_COLUMN, KG1 = SF.getString("KG1",""));
    list.add(temp);


    Loggene adapter=new Loggene(this, list);
                    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view, int position, long id) {
                    int pos = position + 1;
                    Toast.makeText(Logg.this, Integer.toString(pos) + " Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            });


}
```

**Log listview layout**

```
<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="617dp"
    android:id="@+id/listView" />
```

**Listview Activity**

> public class Loggene extends BaseAdapter{

```
    public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list;
    Activity activity;
    TextView txtFirst;
    TextView txtSecond;
    TextView txtThird;
    TextView txtFourth;
    public Loggene(Activity activity, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list){
        super();
        this.activity=activity;
        this.list=list;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }



    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub



        LayoutInflater inflater=activity.getLayoutInflater();

        if(convertView == null){

            convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.logg_item, null);

            txtFirst=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ovelse);
            txtSecond=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Reps);
            txtThird=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Sets);
            txtFourth=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.KG);

        }

        HashMap<String, String> map=list.get(position);
        txtFirst.setText(map.get(FIRST_COLUMN));
        txtSecond.setText(map.get(SECOND_COLUMN));
        txtThird.setText(map.get(THIRD_COLUMN));
        txtFourth.setText(map.get(FOURTH_COLUMN));

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

**Listview Layout**

> 

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Sets"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Reps"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/KG"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
```

**Listview columns class**

> public class Ovelser {
>           public static final String FIRST_COLUMN="First";
>           public static final String SECOND_COLUMN="Second";
>           public static final String THIRD_COLUMN="Third";
>           public static final String FOURTH_COLUMN="Fourth";
>       }

**Result**

[image: MainAct]

[image: Loggact]

What i'm trying to do here is to get input text form the Mainactivity layout to the listview and to be sorted in columns. This part works perfectly. What i cannot figre out is how to add more "items". When i do this the data thats been saved (Trening) in SharedPrefs will be overwritten. So do how could i add more data ? is there perhaps another way i should do this? if so please tell!

Comment: you should look into using a database and a `ContentProvider`, there's plenty of tutorials on that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Youxian stated, your data is being overwritten when put in the same key. Because you are going to repeat this overriding process every day, you will not be able to get an accurate log of daily workout data. Instead, use database to store your data. Here is how shared prefs works:

[image]
(windowsphone.interoperabilitybridges.com)

As you can see in this diagram, they IsolatedStorageSettings is based off of the key/value pairs, which you are overriding right now. That is the way that the compiler even knows what data to get, by the key:

[image]
(kb4dev.com)

So again, I suggest you use either different keys to prevent overriding, or you use data base.

Comment: @Itszani If it worked, I would really appreciate it if you marked my answer best answer. You should see a checkmark under the like button, just click that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

SharedPreference is like key and value, so you always put data in the same key(O1,R1,S1,KG1). The data you stored would be overwritten. if you want to use shared preference anyway, just put values in different keys (like add a counter after key name). and use getAll() method to show them in your list.
you can see these for more information about shared preference:

http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html

Using android SQLite database to do this might be a choice, learn more:

http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html